# How to throw an error when entering wrong date Year in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

The format is dd/mm/yyyy. So if User enters 01/02/0009 then it accepts it. But I want to throw and error if the 1st digit is 0. So that it would be a valid Date as Salesforce accepts 1700-4000 date range. Please suggest. I tried :

```
    if(Number(event.target.value.split('-')[2]) ==  '00' || Number(event.target.value.split('-')[1]) == '00' || (event.target.value!=undefined && event.target.value.split('-')[0].length() == 4 && event.target.value.split('-')[0].subString(0,2)=='00'))
     {
        component.set("v.error","Please enter the correct format for Year");
     }
```

event.target.value.split('-')[2]) -> This is for Date.

event.target.value.split('-')[1]) -> This is for Month.

event.target.value.split('-')[0]) -> This is for Year.

But somehow it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean "if the first digit is zero"? What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: It means date cannot be 00 it should be like 01 or 10 like that..

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to check if the date is invalid is to check if you can construct it (`isNaN` returns true if the date is invalid):

```
if(isNaN(new Date(event.target.value))) {
  // Date is invalid //
}
```

This will not only ensure that the month is a valid value, but also check if the day of the month is valid, such as rejecting 2009-02-29 (2009 is not a leap year).

Comment: Thanks but how will it verify that the year if the year is entered as 0063? It should throw the error even in that unless user entered it as 1993. Please clarify

Comment: Okay so If the user will enter 00/01/0043 or 01/01/0076 then also it will throw the error right?

Comment: @Rene 00/01/0043 is invalid, but 01/01/0076 will be parsed as 01/01/1976. That's just how dates are parsed in most systems. For example, when I write the date for Christmas in 1991, I could write 12/25/91, and everyone would understand that I mean 1991, not the year 91. Aside from that, you can check if the year is valid by using `min` and `max` properties on the field or checking manually after trying to parse the date as in this answer.

Comment: But in my use case it will be failed . I need to restrict the user to not to enter this kind of year.